# WKWebview fail to open WKActionsSheet on presented UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, web

I have a problem with my WKWebViewController.

I use this code to present:

```
    SRWebWKViewController *webcontroller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SRWebViewControllerWKWebview"];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:webcontroller];
    [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

It is presented correctly, but when I press on any link I get this error:

```
 Warning: Attempt to present <WKActionSheet: 0x7fc4f4c6f5e0> on <UINavigationController: 0x7fc4f4b9d9e0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

I searched a lot on the web but I can not find any solution that solves my problem

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Comment: No, unfortunately I have not solved the problem, I folded to the new SafariViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in UIKit from iOS 8.0 until at least iOS 9.3.1.

We've seen this issue in [PSPDFKit](https://pspdfkit.com/) and after investigating the UIKit assembly and `WKWebView` sources we found a workaround that is still horrible, but not invasive.

The main strategy is to be selective and apply a workaround just in time - then clean up again.  You can read the source code here:

https://gist.github.com/steipete/b00fc02aa9f1c66c11d0f996b1ba1265

And please dupe [rdar://26295020](http://www.openradar.me/26295020) so this will get hopefully fixed in time for iOS 10. (The bug exists since iOS 8 and was first reported on iOS 8b5.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.